# Possible Bug in Integrate of sign function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

When integrating the Sign function mathematica seems to give me a wrong result

```
IntSign = (Integrate[Sign[1 - xp], {xp, 0, x}])
Plot[{Sign[1 - x], IntSign}, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image: In orange the integral and in blue the sign function itself]

Why is mathematica calculating this wrong? Or is this my fault?

Note this is version 11.3

Comment: is it still wrong result if you do `IntSign = Integrate[Sign[1 - xp], {xp, 0, x}, Assumptions -> x > 0]` ?

Comment: No in this case it gives the correct result. Now the question is why mathematica gives the wrong result without that extra assumption.

Comment: Possibly a bug, I think

Comment: It's not a bug,Try: `Integrate[Sign[1 - xp], {xp, 0, x}, Assumptions -> x > 1]` , `Out-> 2-x` or `Integrate[Sign[1 - xp], {xp, 0, x}, Assumptions -> -2 < x < 2]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integrate does not seem to be producing a great answer in this case.  I will pass this along to the relevant team for further investigation to see if we can't improve it.

But the first answer is not wrong, in general. Note that while `Sign` is often defined as a piecewise function on the reals, in Mathematica it is a function on the complexes, essentially `x/Abs[x`].  This means it is nowhere differentiable, and therefore not easily integrable, either (the result is contour-dependent).  Since in your original input you provided no conditions on x, `Integrate` attempted to give you an answer valid in some part of the complex plane, and end up with one that is discontinuous.  If you just tell `Integrate` that x is real, it will give you a continuous answer:

```
Integrate[Sign[1 - xp], {xp, 0, x}, Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]]
(* Piecewise[{{2 - x, x > 1}, {x, Inequality[0, Less, x, LessEqual, 1] || x  < 0}}, 0] *)
```

An even easier solution to start out by telling integrate you live in the real world by using `RealSign`.  `RealSign` is equal to `Sign` on the reals, but undefined for complex inputs, allowed many automatic simplications to take place.  For example:

```
Integrate[RealSign[1 - xp], {xp, 0, x}]
(* 1 + Piecewise[{{1 - x, x > 1}}, -1 + x], which is continuous *)
```

Also:

```
D[RealSign[1 - xp], xp]
(* -Piecewise[{{0, 1 - xp != 0}}, Indeterminate] *)
```

Comment: Thank you this is very clear this way. Great!